# Search and filter in list ASP.NET MVC

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to implement search in my list but for some reason, it's not working. I used a jQuery script for searching - please guide me.

Here are my controller and my view:

```
public ActionResult Details(int S)
{
    SLMEntitiesDB dbContext = new SLMEntitiesDB();

    var VL = (from U in dbContext.Users
              join P in dbContext.Products on U.PID equals P.PID
              where P.PID == U.PID
              select new UP()
                         {
                             UserO = U,
                             ProductO = P
                         }).Where(U => U.UserO.LID == S).ToList();

    ViewBag.result = VL;

    return View(ViewBag.result);
}
```

View

```
    @model IEnumerable<SLMDemo0.Models.UP>
    <input type="text" id="txtsearch" placeholder="Search"/>    
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserO.UserName)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ProductO.PName)
            </th>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserO.UserName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductO.PName)
                </td>
               <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.UserO.UID })
    </table>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $("txtsearch").on("keyup", function () {
            var txtenter = $(this).val();
            $("table tr").each(function (results) {
                if (results !== 0) {
                    var id = $(this).find("td:nth-child(2)").text();
                    if (id.indexOf(txtenter) !== 0 && id.toLowerCase().indexOf(txtenter.toLowerCase()) < 0) {
                        $(this).hide();
                    }
                    else {
                        $(this).show(); } } }); }); </script>
```

There's no result from the code, I can view what's in the list but when you type anything in the search nothing is happening.

Comment: You should return `View(result);` to begin with.

Comment: If the list is rendered then there is `#` missing in your selector `$("#txtsearch")`

Answer (score 0):

You have missed the # identifier in `$("txtsearch")`
Please use it with `$("#txtsearch")`

```
<script>
    $("#txtsearch").on("keyup", function () {
        var txtenter = $(this).val();
        $("table tr").each(function (results) {
            if (results !== 0) {
                var id = $(this).find("td:nth-child(2)").text();
                if (id.indexOf(txtenter) !== 0 && id.toLowerCase().indexOf(txtenter.toLowerCase()) < 0) {
                    $(this).hide();
                }
                else {
                    $(this).show(); } } }); }); </script>
```

Comment: after adding the missing #, whenever I type anything in the search, all the records are cleared/gone.

Comment: Please refer to this [link](https://jsfiddle.net/ajrock/f4km3es2/3/), I have used your js and it works fine